# Iterate through the files and replace multple arigument using shell script

Tags: shell

Here is the case.

I have a number of input properties as the following:

```
$Prop1 = value1;
$Prop2 = value2;
$Prop3 = value3;
```

And have a few txt file with the following content(file have different content but the format is the same) under the folder with few subfolder:
Files are located in the folder with few subfolders.

```
{{Prop1}}.{{Prop2}}
{{Prop2}}-{{Prop3}}
{{Prop1}}:{{Prop4}}:{{Prop2}}-{{Prop4}}
${Argument1} = {{Prop1}}.{{Prop2}}.{{Prop3}}.{{Prop4}}
```

Could some please help me with solving next cases:

1. Iterate through folder and subfolder find files that end with *.txt
2. For all funded files, "{{Prop*}}" should be replaced with corresponding $Prop* value. For example: "{{Prop1}}" should become "value1"
3. IF "{{Prop*}}" does not exist(in our case "{{Prop4}}") do not replace anything and raise error
4. "${Argument*}" should not be touched and should remain the same
5. Original file should not be changed and new files with replacement should be created under another location

Thanks in advance

UPD:

Comment: Please add your code and what you've tried so far, this will enable people to help you.

Comment: Why do you have this tagged `ruby`?

Comment: This code is not valid Ruby code. Please, clean up your code and make sure that it at least parses correctly before you post it!

Comment: My task is to do it or using shell or ruby? ruby removed since almost compled with shell. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl can handle this kind of conditional search & replace

```
#!/bin/bash

Prop1=value1
Prop2=value2
Prop3=value3

export Prop1 Prop2 Prop3

shopt -s globstar 

perl -i.bak -pe '
    s[ ( \{\{ (.+?) \}\} ) ]
     [ 
        if (exists $ENV{$2}) {
            $ENV{$2}
        } else {
            warn "unknown property $2 in file $ARGV\n";
            $1
        } 
     ]gex
' **/*.txt
```

The `e` flag to the `s///` command allows you to run arbitrary perl code in the replacement block

Running it:

```
$ bash replace_props.sh 
unknown property Prop4 in file sub1/file.txt
unknown property Prop4 in file sub1/file.txt
unknown property Prop4 in file sub1/file.txt
$ cat sub1/file.txt
value1.value2
value2-value3
value1:{{Prop4}}:value2-{{Prop4}}
${Argument1} = value1.value2.value3.{{Prop4}}
```